# Is there a way to spoof ip address when fetching content from a page through PHP

Tags: php, curl, header

Heyy guys

I'm trying to know if it's possible to spoof my server ip address while I fetch content from an url through file_get_contents/curl. I tried **X-Forwarded-For** with curl but [REMOTE_ADDRESS] on second page (page that is being fetched) is still the same as my real server address .

> How can I fetch content from
>   example.com/1234.php, what code should
>   I put on my page 
>   (example.com/abcd.php) so that when
>   [REMOTE_ADDRESS] is called on
>   example.com/1234.php It is something I
>   sent from abcd.php

I did some researching and few say there are ways, I tried few but couldn't understand how  most of them work nor could get results

I know it sounds black (that's what makes it exciting), I promise I won't use it on other sites (still would be interesting to know)

Answer (score 2):

You're better off going with an anonymous proxy. All you're doing by adding the header is making the server think you're a proxy, but chances are your IP is still the visible one.

Some servers even re-check the IP when it sees those headers to verify, and chances are you won't allow incoming connections. ;-) (And anonymous proxies don't send headers or disclose their source, they just make the initial request and blindly pass along the information back to the client).

Comment: Thanks Brad! I have no idea how to do that, I'll do my research on that

Answer (score 1):

Other than a proxy, there's no practical way to spoof an IP address in a way that lets you actually do a full TCP transaction. The sole exception to this is if you control all the routers between you and the target server.

Basically, TCP requires a 3-way handshake before any data can flow. If you spoof your IP address, only the first stage of this 3-way will go through, as the initial response from the target will go to the spoofed IP address, not to you. Think of it was writing the wrong return address on an envelope. You can send the first of a chain of letters to someone, but their response will go whereever the return address says to, which is NOT your address.

Comment: This has been very useful Marc, I understand how it works now, **Is there a way to behave like anonymous proxy through php? or have I understood it all wrong?**

Comment: You're looking at it backwards. You could put a PHP-based proxy on your server, but it'd only be anonymous for ANYONE ELSE using it. If you were to use it, the connections to your target server would still be initiated from YOUR server and therefore directly traceable to you. You need to use someone ELSE's proxy server to hide your activitives.